# flutter/dart duration difference in hours

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi there  in my code i have to return if the date is older than 24 hours than it should return me the date and if not it should return me the difference in hours.

```
publishtime: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 10));

_getTime() {
       String time;
       DateTime now = DateTime.now();
       Duration difference = publishtime.difference(now);
   
       if (difference.inHours > 24) {
         var format = DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
         time = format.format(publishtime);
       } else {
         time = difference.inHours.toString().replaceAll('-', '') + " hours ago";
       }
   return time;   
}
```

it returns me "240 hours ago" but it should return me the date

why dont the `if (difference.inHours > 24)` work as it should? the `difference.inHours` also return a int value so why dont it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here `Duration difference = publishtime.difference(now);` it should be `Duration difference = now.difference(publishtime);`

Or you can use `abs()` at your difference, same result.

Comment: With the [`DateTime.operator -` extension](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/date_time_basics/DateTimeBasics/operator_minus.html) from `package:basics`, it would be `Duration difference = now - publishtime;`, which I personally find more readable and less ambiguous than using `DateTime.difference`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, `difference.inHours` evaluates to -240, not 240. This is because the dates are the wrong way around to how you want them.